# Anyone know of a good Rich Text Edit Control for .NET?

Tags: richtextbox

There seems to be a ton of ASP.NET RTE controls, but I can't seem to locate any good WinForm RichText controls for .NET. The one that cones stock with Visual Studio 2008 does not have any toolbar for choosing font, bold, italics, underline, alignment, etc. A free control would would obviously be preferable, but I don't mind paying a little for a good quality control (royalty free, of course).